# is the function $u=2x-3y+5$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Is the function $u=2x-3y+5$ uniformly continuous in the infinite plane $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: What have you tried?   Do you know that $u$ is continuous in $E$?  What would be the obstacle to uniform continuity?

Comment: so I have some trouble with understanding $E^2=\left\lbrace x<+\infty, y<+\infty \right\rbrace$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vert x-a\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ and $\vert y-b\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{6}$, then
$\vert 2x-3y+5-2a+3b-5\vert\leq 2\vert x-a\vert + 3\vert y-b\vert<2\frac{\epsilon}{4}+3\frac{\epsilon}{6}=\epsilon$.